# a tag without line-decoration in Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I would like to have a link that looks just like plain text except for the cursor by using as few css as possible.

The problem: `<a>` has a blue color (that darkens when hovered) and also has underline on hover. I want it to look like plain text (black without underline).

By using the Bootstrap class "text-dark" I managed to get rid of the blue color.
But how do I get rid of the underline (text-decoration) **without writing css**?

```css
.no-underline:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<span>Standard text</sapn>
<hr>
<a href="#">Standard a tag. Different colors and underline on hover</a>
<hr>
<a href="#" class="text-dark">a tag with text-dark class. Note underline on hover</a>
<hr>
<a href="#" class="text-dark no-underline">a tag with text-dark class and css to disable underline on hover</a>
```

Comment: Other option is to use inline CSS - <a href="#" class="text"  style="text-decoration: none;">

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are several Bootstrap 4 classes that set `text-decoration: none`. Without knowing the semantic context of the link, I suggest you use the `.btn` class...

```
<a href="#" class="text-dark btn">a tag with text-dark class and css to disable underline on hover</a>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/CIt6zI0Iqw

However, there may be a class that works better semantically such as `nav-link` (inside nav), `card-link` (inside cards), or `.breadcrumb-item`. Also, note that Bootstrap 4 only applies the underline to anchor links with the `href=""` attribute. A simple anchor anchor will not have an underline on hover.

Comment: Bootsrap 4.3.1 does have an underline on hover regardless of href attribute

Comment: I'm using 4.5.3 and by default all links have an underline, especially in `card-link` and applying the `.text-decoration-none` class makes no difference, am I missing something?

Answer (score 34):

Bootstrap 4 has the class  "text-decoration-none"

```
<a href="#" class="text-decoration-none">no underline</a>
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/text/#text-decoration

Comment: How do you make it work on hover? Obviously without writing it in CSS and using bootstrap tag.